# How to round a real number?

Tags: vdm++

Say I wanted to round a real number to a natural number, how could I do this in VDM++? The MATH library does not appear to have any function that does this.

Thanks,
Ricardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "floor" operator in VDM. This returns the largest integer that is less than or equal to its argument.

```
> p floor 1.23
= 1
Executed in 0.034 secs. 
> p floor -1.23
= -2
Executed in 0.002 secs. 
> p floor 123
= 123
Executed in 0.001 secs. 
>
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you haven't seen it, the VDM Language Reference Manual explains all the operators: http://raw.github.com/overturetool/documentation/master/documentation/VDM10LangMan/VDM10_lang_man.pdf